# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) how to resolve?

Tags: python, json

```
import json
filename = 'username.json'
try:
    with open(filename) as fo:
        username = json.loads(fo)
except FileNotFoundError:
    user = input("Tell me your username?  ")
    print("I'll remember you next time! " + user + " !")
    with open(filename ,'w') as fo:
        json.dump(user ,fo)
else:
    print("So we meet again " +userame +" !")
```

output:

```
PS C:\Users\gagan\Desktop\python crash course> python jsonfile.pyTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsonfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    username = json.loads(str(fo))
  File "C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: your file(`'username.json'`) might not be in a correct json format.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the file handle to `json.loads`, which expects a string. Instead you either want to use `json.load` (no 's'):

```
username = json.load(fo)
```

Or use `json.loads` (with the 's' at the end, which stands for 'string') with the file *contents*:

```
username = json.loads(fo.read())
```

Comment: The error occurs on line 5, Nikolas is likely correct.

Comment: @darshvader Yes, exactly.

Comment: Just an irrelevant nit-pick, it's not called `json.loads` because `loads` is the plural of `load`. The extra `s` at the end stands for `str` :)

Comment: @MatiasCicero You are absolutely right ;) That was not the best way to describe it: I will update.